# How REGEX can help to extract only the link that contains certain words?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to scrape a website and I want to extract a link that have this pattern: `/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=`

Is it possible to get it done using regex? Below is my script :

```
title = soup.find_all('tbody')
for i in title:
    for link in i.find_all('a'):
        print(link['href'])

/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/company-profile?stock_code=7374
/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393738
/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/company-profile?stock_code=1201
/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393742
/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/company-profile?stock_code=6874
/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393583
/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/company-profile?stock_code=4634
/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393572
/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/company-profile?stock_code=8176
/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393745
/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/company-profile?stock_code=9474
/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393579
/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/company-profile?stock_code=4561
/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393743
/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/company-profile?stock_code=2577
/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393576
/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/company-profile?stock_code=2984
/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393575
/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/company-profile?stock_code=2828
/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393739
/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/company-profile?stock_code=6874
/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393737
/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/company-profile?stock_code=6181
/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393748
/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/company-profile?stock_code=2984
/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393582
/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/company-profile?stock_code=0021
/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393578
/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/company-profile?stock_code=5028
/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393740
/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/company-profile?stock_code=6246
/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393573
/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/company-profile?stock_code=1201
/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393571
/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/company-profile?stock_code=7143
/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393577
/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/company-profile?stock_code=0091
/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393747
/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/company-profile?stock_code=7722
/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393581
/media-releases-rss.rss
```

Comment: Do you want the digits after the `ann_id=` par?

Comment: yes, i want the digits after ann_id=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex, just escape the ? symbol with ? and use regex101.com to check your regex.

```
links = ['/trade/trading_resources/listing_directory/company-profile?stock_code=7374/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id=393738',
         'some_other_link']

for link in links:
    if re.search('/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details\?ann_id=', link):
        use_this_link = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regex for something like this, it would be better to use the `in` operator to check if the link contains the substring.

You can do something like:

```py
substring = "/market_information/announcements/company_announcement/announcement_details?ann_id="

title = soup.find_all('tbody')
for i in title:
    for link in i.find_all('a'):
        if substring in link:
            print(link) # This is the link that contained that substring
```